Spyder: An error ocurred while starting the kernel. Cannot run conda install spyder-kernels=2.4
I set up a virtual environment with python 3.7.9
Spyder runs on 3.11 and I changed the interpreter to 3.7.9. I am using Anaconda3
The console in Spyder shows the following error message:
"An error ocurred while starting the kernel
You can install it by activating your environment first (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
You can install it by activating your environment first (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
conda install spyder-kernels=2.4"
I therefore activated my virtual environment in the Anaconda Prompt and entered  conda install spyder-kernels=2.4.
However I get :
"failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
Specifications:

spyder-kernels=2.4 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0|>=3.12,<3.13.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7.9
If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that."
Not sure what needs to be done from there. Help really appreciated.
I tried running "conda install spyder-kernels=2.4" outside my virtual environment
